# Is a PK of type bytea slower compared to a PK of a sequential type integer in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a project where I have to store millions of rows with a column `x` of type `bytea` (with a maximum size of 128 bytes). I need to query the data by `x` (i.e. `where x = ?`). Now I was wondering if I can use `x` directly as a primary key without any negative performance impact?

I also have to join that table on the primary key from another table, therefore I would also have to store `bytea` as foreign key in another table.

As far as I know, most database systems make use of a B+-Tree which has a search complexity of `θ(log(n))`. When using `bytea` as primary key, I am not sure if Postgres can efficiently organize such a B+-Tree?

Comment: 128 bytes takes more space than 4 bytes. And these keys have to be read into memory buffers. But if they must  be unique, you would still need an unique index on them.

Comment: Totally agree with that and yes, `x` has to be unique.

Comment: If there is also a FK referring to this table, (in most cases) it would be better to use a serial as *surrogate* PK, and refer to the surrogate.This will avoid duplicating the *fat* key in the supporting index for the FK.

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is my alternative solution too but it would make things a bit more complicated caused by the types of queries I am performing (which would implicate more joins, ...). But beside that, I was looking for some performance benchmarks that can help me to "verify my idea".

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that the value of the `bytea` never changes, you can use it as primary key.

But it is not necessarily wise to do so: if that key is stored in other tables as well, this will waste space, and an artificial primary key might be better.